# Using Plex and Snap apps. Mounting issues

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, fstab, plex

I have a drive mounting issue, and I think it has to do with the way Nautilus takes ownership of my mounted drives.

I have an NTFS partition mounted in /media through /etc/fstab. In this configuration, my snap apps (eg. VLC) is able to access my files, however Plex cannot see the media files.

If I mount my NTFS partition in any other location, such as /disks, then Plex works fine. However, now my snap apps cannot access files on the mounted partition.

What's the best solution so all my apps can work nicely together?

Comment: How do you have it mounted through your `/etc/fstab`?  Mine works fine in the configuration for snap apps and Plex Media Server.  Mine is configured in my `fstab` file like `UUID=a50fd553-b143-4ad8-bdb1-2247d9349e86 /media/storage   ext4    defaults 0 0`.  I did have this same configuration for a NTFS partition on another computer and Plex Media Server was able to still see all the media.

Comment: I have it mounted in [fstab] as [UUID=505890B358909988 /media/user/TV/ ntfs-3g auto,nofail,user,rw 0 0]. Plex can see the foder TV, but not the mounted drives and files.

Comment: I would try creating it's own mount point in the `/media` folder like `sudo mkdir -p /media/TV` then remove the TV folder from the `/media/user/` folder.  This will leave the `/media/user/` folder open for auto mounts.  Then do your fstab entry like so.  This is one I have been using for the media on an external 3TB drive I have been using:  `UUID="6AAA4323AA42EB61" /media/Seagate ntfs defaults,nofail 0 0`  and that one has not given me any issues at all.